# How to share data between scheduled jobs

Tags: java, windows, quartz-scheduler

I am writing a scheduler which grabs XML data and inserts into MySQL DB - simple isn't. But the problem or the logic that I am trying to find is here. **NOTE:** I want to execute this in windows environment in future it might be configured for other platforms.

1. Scheduler should run on every 5 mins.
2. This script should fetch condition/configuration on what to parse and collect the data-fields from XML and these conditions are available from MySQL table.
3. This table also defines a delay in which this script should check for the difference in the XML fields & delay.
4. This script does both, one is running for every 5 mins to collect XML and check the difference in the table (MySQL) for every said delay.
5. This script then reads the XML data-fields and parses it, then collects only those data-fields that is defined from the above MySQL table.
6. The collected data will be inserted into MySQL DB only when there is change in the state and this state is defined from MySQL table.

Feedback/Suggestions:

1. Due to the delay, I am not sure how should I store the configuration in the script which will be shared between each schedules.
2. Is there anyway to use `static` variable in the code to store this data? Which will be shared b/w different jobs? or different schedules?
3. Basically, how should I implement this? A better approach in terms of performance.

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE:**

One of the suggestion is to use Java Code as a windows service (?) we could have some common data shared between different jobs? - does it make sense?

Reference:
[Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurensy is the answer, try creating Thread pool or Executor servises, and stop certain threads for 5min , you coud even use Synchronization if few threads will be working with the same resource.
Remember not always the more threads use the faster you will finish your job f.e. 3 threads- 2 min
5threads-6 min

*Read tutorial about threads

*create fe simple threads with wait for 5 min

*read some tutorials about thread pool/synchnizations and sharing resourses (script part)
*test to find the most optimal way